# What's the best android Log strategy for a team?

Tags: android, exception, logging, coding-style

We always log the exception when develop android apps. And we want to standardize the formate and strategy to prevent e.printStackTrace() or unnecessary log from being printed?

So what's the best strategy?

Shall we implement the 
   `Log.x(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr)` 
to 
   `Log.x(tag, msg+tr.toString())`?

Please give me some suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

- Create a custom `Log` class.
- make each class import this instead of `android.util.Log`

  ```
  public class Log{
  public static final boolean enableInfo      = false;
  public static final boolean enableError     = true;
  public static final boolean enableDebug     = true;
  public static final boolean enableVerbose   = false;

  public static void i(String tag, String msg) {
      if(enableInfo) {
          android.util.Log.i(tag,msg);
      }
  }
  public static void e(String tag, String msg) {
      if(enableError) {
          android.util.Log.e(tag,msg);
      }
  }
  public static void e(String tag, String msg, Exception e) {
      if(enableError) {
          android.util.Log.e(tag,msg, e);
      }
  }
  public static void v(String tag, String msg) {
      if(enableVerbose) {
          android.util.Log.v(tag,msg);
      }
  }
  public static void d(String tag, String msg) {
      if(enableDebug) {
          android.util.Log.d(tag,msg);
      }
  }
  ```

  }
- using this technique you can enable and disable the logs in the whole application by just changing the constants in a single file, for when you have to make a build to release your application, etc.

  ```
  public static final boolean enableInfo      = false;
  public static final boolean enableError     = true;
  public static final boolean enableDebug     = true;
  public static final boolean enableVerbose   = false;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are errors and thus to highlight them I always prefer to use Log.e in android. I always go with Log.e(LOG_TAG,e.getMessage());. I would always like to keep my exception/throwable messages short but meaningful. Sometimes you can print out your own log message like Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Divide by zero error");

Its up to you which suits you better.

Answer (score 0):

You definately want to use Log.e/w/d/i 
I wrape it into another function call so that I can hide them in the release version but simply testing for a boolean constant in the function call